# I am not able to import python module textblob

Tags: python

I have already installed the `textblog` module using the `pip install` command
but when importing the module using

```
from textblob import TextBlob
```

I get an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textbolb'`

Comment: Are you sure you typed `textblob` and not `textbolb`?

Comment: Please check your question, there seems to be a typo? you have installed the `textblog` module but you are trying to import another module.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install:

```
      pip3 install textblob
```

`pip` install library in lower version of python but `pip3` install library in python3 or up.

Comment: Did you mean `pip3 install textblob`?

Answer (score 0):

you can downlaod the package by using 'wheel' file from the link 
https://pypi.org/project/textblob/#files
and put that wheel file in Script folder and use the same cmd their

```
pip install <wheel file>
```